# GyroUpdates and restart scene mutated while enumerated crashing (SpriteKit and Swift)

Tags: iphone, swift, crash, sprite-kit, nsarray

I have a Swift SpriteKit scene and it doesn't happen every time but I did some testing on the restart game button by pressing menu and restart in quick successions repeatedly till it crashes. It also crashes randomly from other points that load the scene. My estimate is that theres about a 30% chance that it will crash on this line

> class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

with with the following error:

> 2015-03-07 09:52:14.347 DDgame[1457:433285] *** Terminating app due
>   to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection
>   <__NSArrayM: 0x170051e50> was mutated while being enumerated.'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x18342259c 0x193b6c0e4 0x183421f50 0x187a57538 0x187a56c84 0x187a5661c 0x187a56510 0x10008f4c0
>   0x1000913b0 0x187a46bcc 0x187a43fd8 0x187a41038 0x187a6dfd8
>   0x100360a9c 0x187575280 0x187575118 0x1845718d0 0x1833c55e4
>   0x1833da200 0x1833da160 0x1833d80e0 0x1833050a4 0x18c49f5a4
>   0x187c36aa4 0x1000d1204 0x1000d1244 0x1941daa08) libc++abi.dylib:
>   terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

I used an catch all exception breakpoint and found out it is crashing in my update method on the gyro updates. Does anyone have a safer way of keeping gyro going safely with an update button?

Here is an extract of the touchesBegan method, I've removed the code sitting inside the other buttons just not to create too much fluff here: (not sure if you guys need the extras here?)

```
            else if node.name == "replayButton" {

                    if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
                        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: "pauseGame", object: nil)


                        let transition = SKTransition.revealWithDirection(SKTransitionDirection.Down, duration: 1.0)

                        scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill

                        self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
            }
```

I have discovered that it is crashing on the gyro updates in the update method:

```
override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
    var timeSinceLast = currentTime - lastUpdateTimeInterval
    lastUpdateTimeInterval = currentTime

    if(!gameOver) {
        //check for gameover
        if (self.goldStash <= 0) {   
            gameOver = true
            gameIsPaused = true
            self.gameOverMethod()
        }


        //spawning logic
        spawnEngine()
        //gyro update
        if (self.motionManager.gyroData != nil) {
            self.updateGyroNodeWithData(self.childNodeWithName("GoldBack") as? SKSpriteNode, gyroIn: motionManager.gyroData)
            self.updateGyroNodeWithDataReverse(self.childNodeWithName("GoldFront") as? SKSpriteNode, gyroIn: motionManager.gyroData)
            self.updateGyroNode(self.childNodeWithName("CBack1") as? SKSpriteNode, gyroIn: motionManager.gyroData, minIn: cBack1position.x-10.0, maxIn: cBack1position.x+10.0, sensitivity: 0.8)
            self.updateGyroNode(self.childNodeWithName("CBack2") as? SKSpriteNode, gyroIn: motionManager.gyroData, minIn: cBack2position.x-10.0, maxIn: cBack2position.x+10.0, sensitivity: 0.8)
            self.updateGyroNode(self.childNodeWithName("CBack3") as? SKSpriteNode, gyroIn: motionManager.gyroData, minIn: cBack3position.x-10.0, maxIn: cBack3position.x+10.0, sensitivity: 0.8)
            self.updateGyroNode(self.childNodeWithName("CBack4") as? SKSpriteNode, gyroIn: motionManager.gyroData, minIn: cBack4position.x-10.0, maxIn: cBack4position.x+10.0, sensitivity: 0.8)
        } 
    }

    if timeSinceLast > 1 {
        timeSinceLast = kMinTimeInterval
    }
    updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate(timeSinceLast)
}

func updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate(timeSinceLast: NSTimeInterval) {
    for dwarf in dwarves {
        dwarf.updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate(timeSinceLast)
    }

}
```

Comment: These pesky errors usually happen when the GameScene starts enumerating through arrays containing objects which are still in the process of modifying. Try using a BOOL, in the GameScene update method, to indicate when all initial setup actions are done before running code in said method. If that is not the issue, only modify an array used in the GameScene update method while in the GameScene update method.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. It was in this piece of code:

```
self.childNodeWithName("GoldBack") as? SKSpriteNode
```

It kept enumerating the scene for the nodes while the scene was then destroyed. I tried putting in a boolean to prevent the gyro updates running while the menu was open but for some reason it kept crashing, the percentage dropped significantly but something wasn't working.

The best solution was to create variables of the nodes in the init instead and then run gyro updates on those in the update method.

```
var goldBack = SKSpriteNode?()

goldBack = self.childNodeWithName("GoldBack") as? SKSpriteNode
```

Then in the update method:

```
self.updateGyroNodeWithData(goldBack, gyroIn: motionManager.gyroData)
```

I didn't know about this before but, another thing that really helped me was adding 'All Exceptions' breakpoint in Xcode. (This is done by going to the breakpoint navigator, pressing the + on the bottom left and add exception breakpoint)